# Emacs forms-mode: multiple forms for one file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way in forms-mode, to have multiple different "forms-format-lists" which depend on 
the record currently being read into the buffer? For example, say I have 5 different types of
records in my file, all with different fields, but each record type is categorized by say field
number 1. Is it possible to define based on the value of a field number, which form is loaded for
a particular record? i.e. a file with both student and teacher records, and field number one starts
with either "T" or "S". If it begins with "T", load the teacher's form, else the student one.

Answer (score 1):

Probably working with temporary files is closest to existing code.

Create  forms-student.el resp. forms-teacher.el  matching your data-types.

Than a command for traveling source code, (when (looking-at... ) - which writes a teacher-temp or students-temp data. Afterwards call forms-teacher.el resp. forms-student.el upon them accordingly.

Writing temps might be avoided, which needs some more tweaks, reading from buffers, not file etc.